# My laptop boots with full screen brightness and full keyboard backlight

Tags: boot, keyboard, laptop, screen, brightness

I meets a problem that my laptop boots with full screen brightness and full keyboard backlight.

According to a post on Ubuntu forum for Macbook (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1987790), it is possible to fix it by editing /etc/rc.local. However, it do not work on my ASUS Zenbook UX32VD. Moreover, I want to disable the touchpad by default.

Could you please tell me the methods to deal with these problems?

[image]
[image]

***Thank you for your attention.***

---

Related websites :

1. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1987790
2. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/save-blacklight-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Answer (score 1):

It works here. I've added
chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
to my rc.local and I can now do
echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
which works as expected. Brand new Zenbook UX301LA, Linux tpc 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: `casper@casper-UX32VD:/etc$ chmod a+w rc.local`
`chmod: changing permissions of ‘rc.local’: Operation not permitted` How to deal with this problem?

Comment: I used "sudo" to change the permission to a+w and added like what you add. However, whatever what I try to add, the full screen brightness still exists.

Comment: I meant: add "chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness" to your rc.local